# Physical object, carried by a person, that represents an encumbrance

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, is-it-a-word, metaphors

I believe a word currently exists that is used as a metaphor to mean something similar to, "a person is (willingly?) carrying a physical object, but there is no benefit to carrying (or transporting) the object and the carrying of the object is a significant burden to the person."

The meaning of this word/metaphor is closely related to the [albatross metaphor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albatross_%28metaphor%29) from *The Rime of the Ancient Mariner*. In the poem, the mariner does not literally have the albatross hanging from his neck, however, even though he feels as if it were hanging from his neck. If the word I am looking for actually exists (and is not a mistaken memory of mine), the object/metaphor will be something that the person literally carries or holds.

I mistakenly believed that "lodestone" had this meaning, but I looked up the word and discovered that it merely means a magnetic stone. Oops: I am glad I checked.

I am not looking for words or phrases that are similar to shackles, ball and chain, hobbled, or Sisyphean task. The defects of those phrases involve one or more of the following: the condition is involuntary, the condition cannot be reversed or abandoned, it does not involve a physical object that is literally carried by the person.

### Possible conclusions

1. The word exists.
2. In the tradition of misheard song lyrics, I believe that Jimi Hendrix would like to take a break and [kiss this guy](https://www.yahoo.com/music/bp/-excuse-me-while-i-kiss-that-guy---music-s-6-most-misheard-lyrics-210920136.html).
3. There is a word or phrase that is close to what I believe exists, but not exactly what I believe exists.
4. A motorcycle does not have doors.

Comment: There's also [millstone](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/millstone), but that's metaphorical as well.

Comment: I remember reading [*The Pilgrim's Progress*](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/131/131-h/131-h.htm) as a child. It was a copy aimed at children (doubtless with simplified text), and there was a little drawing at the start of each chapter - often showing "The Pilgrim" ("Christian", the narrator) with a great big shaggy "haversack" on his back. About halfway through I was fascinated to notice that the haversack got progressively smaller in successive depictions. It was called a ***burden*** in the text, but even that was obviously a metaphoric reference (to the weight of Christian's past sins).

Comment: He ain't heavy, he's my brother

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term *[millstone](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/millstone)* is often used to reflect such a burden

> A heavy and inescapable responsibility:
>   *she threatened to become a millstone around his neck*

*Oxford Dictionary Online*

Comment: Ah, yes. That is the word I was trying to recall, and it seems that I also mis-remembered the precise meaning.

Comment: Evidently not what you were looking for, but as an expression, there’s also the somewhat similar _we all have our cross(es) to bear_, which fits rather nicely into the definition you gave and involves carrying a physical object metaphorically, too.

Comment: +1, but how did "millstone" become the exemplar of this scenario? Merely because a millstone is exceptionally heavy, or is there a backstory?

Comment: *Millstone* in such usage, is from the Christian scriptures, where Jesus is written to have said, "better that a millstone be hanged around your/his neck and thrown into the sea".

Comment: And there is always the concept of [*excess baggage*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/excess-baggage)

Answer (score 5):

There is the term ***dead weight***

Defined by [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dead+weight) as:

> 2. an oppressive burden; encumbrance

It can be used to refer to extra weight with no benefit. 
For example you might ask someone,

> "Why are you carrying around all that ***dead weight***?"